# issue with single double quotes in php

Tags: php, html

I am having issue with single and double quotes in function and its parameters. Here is my code

```
$prev_page_arrow= "<span class='pagn_prev' onclick=\"send($where,'Page_{$this->name}=$prev&amp;{$this->rppGet}{$this->query_string}#$this->anchor');\" >Prev</span>";
```

The problem is with my `$where` parameter in `send` function. `$where` variable has values like

`$where = purpose="buy" and city="cityname"`

OR

`$where = purpose='buy' and city='cityname'`

I can make `$where` property value in both `single` and `double` quotes. The issue is when value is in `double quotes`, it ends the function paramter. For example

```
$prev_page_arrow= "<span class='pagn_prev' onclick=\"send(purpose="buy",'Page_{$this->name}=$prev&amp;{$this->rppGet}{$this->query_string}#$this->anchor');\" >Prev</span>";
```

The `double` quotes here means, end of function with parameters. Similarly if I do it with `single` quote, it means end of parameter.

How it can be solved?

Comment: Please avoid mixing HTML and PHP in such way. Use ".addslashes($where)." maybe?

Comment: Is there any solution in the way i did? ;)

Comment: I edited first comment. Basically it is not good idea to make string variable which is made of other string variables which are also made of another variables. Too messy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest putting your "where" value inside a `data-*` attribute instead of trying to embed it in an inline event handler. For that matter, you shouldn't be using inline handlers anyway.

The point is, try this:

```
$prev_page_arrow="<span class='pagn_prev' data-where=\"".htmlspecialchars($where)."\"
     onclick=\"send(this.getAttribute('data-where'),'Page_........');\">Prev</span>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will work?

```
$prev_page_arrow= "<span class='pagn_prev' onclick='send(purpose=\"buy\", \"Page_{$this->name}=$prev&amp;{$this->rppGet}{$this->query_string}#$this->anchor\");' >Prev</span>";
```

Comment: hmm, sounds ok. Let me try it.